# How I can set proxy URL from the external config.json file in vue.config.json

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

How we can set Proxy URL from a config.json external file like in .net applications we do configuration through web.config.
I am using the vue-cli boilerplate (Vue2 + webpack) + vuex + axios.

I did some work for it but it's not helpful, I import the config.json and use the configuration data from it but after build webpack including that config file in output.min.js

Currently, I am manually changing the server URL in the code before running a build for a production server or a build for a development server but the requirement is needed to use config.json file separately so I will be able to change proxy URL from the config file on the production.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. If you are using vue cli 3, you can use https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy is that not sufficient?

Comment: I want to set a proxy URL from an external JSON file as that file will be used for app configuration and want to exclude from bundling when you build the project, webpack do bundling and minify the file on the build. After build changing the proxy URL from the minified file is difficult for DevOps user.

Comment: vue cli 3 uses the `vue.config.js`, so since it is not json, you can include logic in the configuration file, so that should allow you to call the data from an external file.

Comment: I think you didn't get the requirement. Did you know about bundling and minification? or do you have knowledge of webpack?

Comment: If you want to be able to change it easily *after* it's been bundled, put it into a separate _js_ file (so you don't need ajax to load it), and use vue/webpack code splitting to generate a separate resource.

Comment: Yes, I want to change it easily after it's been bundled. I have already tried if you read my question, I put data in the separate file but the problem is that when I access to file data for setting the proxy URL in vue cli 3 then that file is going to be a part of the bundle. And I have no idea how can I split from the bundle vue.config.js or created one separated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize webpack code splitting with the `webpackChunkName` comment. This will create a separate chunk, which can then be altered easier after build.

Here is the code to have it available inside a vue component

#### config.json:

```
{
  "abc": 123,
  "def": 123
}
```

#### vue component:

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      config: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    import (/* webpackChunkName: "config", webpackMode: "lazy-once" */ "./config.json").then(r => this.config = r.default);
  }
}
```

#### outside of component

```js
let config;
import(/* webpackChunkName: "config" */ './config.js')
  .then(r => {config : r.default})
  .then(/* do stuff with config */);
```

Some things to note:
- because it is no longer part of the same bundle, the config bundle will need to come from a network request, which means that the response is **asynchronous**, so you cannot do a simple assignment. This may require less-than-trivial change to your code, as you won't be able to use the value before it is loaded, so any other code that relies on it will need to wait. 
- whether you use json, or js file in source, the resulting webpack bundle will be a js file and will be almost the same, though the json version is slightly smaller

the config bundle will look something like this

```js
(window["webpackJsonp"]=window["webpackJsonp"]||[]).push([["config"],{"7dc5":function(n){n.exports={abc:123,def:123}}}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=config.26910bd8.js.map
```

where `{abc:123,def:123}` is the data part that should be easy to modify now

resources:

- webpack code splitting documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
- lazy-loading, showing the feature in vue https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk

Comment: Thanks @Daniel it's helpful for me